# React class decorator that set's display name from class name

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-decorator

I would like to have a decorator that set's the static property `displayName` of decorated class to the name of the class. Usage would look like this:

```
@NamedComponent
class Component extends React.Component {
    \* ... *\
}
```

This would be in my opinion much better way to solve [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4081) than the suggested workaround. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

A decorator can't get class name out of nowhere. There's no place where it can get it when minified code is evaluated. Original code will be transpiled in production to something like:

```
let b = a(class b extends c {...})
```

Where `NamedComponent` decorator becomes `a` and `Component` class becomes `b`.

It's possible but only if a decorator specifies the name explicitly as a string:

```
@NamedComponent('Component')
class Component extends React.Component {
    \* ... *\
}
```

At this point this isn't any better than doing this without a decorator:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    static displayName = 'Component';
    \* ... *\
}
```

Comment: Oh right, the component name will be minified when the decorator is ran. Could this be solved with reflection metadata or is that minified as well?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist as metadata either. You can get some interesting metadata with emitDecoratorMetadata TS option but function names aren't there. What's the purpose? Debugging?

Comment: Yeah since the component names are minified the virutal DOM preview in React debugging tools is hard to search through.

Comment: I don't think there are better options than explicit `displayName` assignment for programmatically created component names like `Connect(...)`.

Comment: Ok so I've just decided to set webpack build mode to development so the names won't be minified.